# TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead. robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

When I tried to add the string value to the list in the robot frame work. I am getting below error. Can anyone help me here?

**Error:Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead.**

```
${a}=  'H'

Append_to_list       ${Elementlist2}    ${a}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that `${Elementlist2}` is a string, not a list. It must be a list if you are using [Append to list](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Append%20To%20List)

Comment: yes i agree then we can not add the value as string to the List

Comment: @LikithKumar: you _can_ add a value as a string to a list. That's precisely what `Append to list` is for. That's not what you're doing.  You're trying to add a string to a _string_. That's what the error is telling you, and what I said in my answer.